# Complex Numbers: Im having a problem solving this.

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been working some problems solving and simplifying basic complex numbers. I'm really stuck at this one; I haven't an idea where to begin solving.

If $\frac{3+2j}{5+4j} = 2x + j^5y$, Then (x:y) = ??

I'd prefer someone explain how to do it than just answer it.
But any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by $(x:y)$?

Comment: And presumably, $j=i$.

Comment: I'm in the dark here myself buddy. But my guess is that it ends up being a simultaneous equation since the answer must be given in (x:y) form.

Comment: yes! My lecturer uses j in place of the more widely used i. A textbook I use, called Engineering mathematics by K A Stroud, also uses j instead of i. but yes, j=i

Comment: Yes, J^2 = -1, and J=i

Comment: If you don't know what $(x:y)$ is, then (since we also don't know), we can't really help you. We are in the position of a doctor recieving a patient saying "my splurgl hurts".

Comment: Also, is j^5y meant to represent $j^{5y}$ or $j^5 y$?

Comment: The question is now edited as it should be, just check again

Comment: @5xum It doesn't really make a lot of sense for it to be $j^{5y}$ in the context of such a question.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Well, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $x$ and $y$ are real here. As $j^5=j^4\cdot j=j$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{3+2j}{5+4j}=2x+jy\implies\frac{23}{41}-\frac{2}{41}j=2x+jy\implies x=\frac{23}{82}\,\wedge\,y=-\frac{2}{41},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
(x:y)=\left(\frac{23}{82}:-\frac{2}{41}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm guessing that $(x:y)$ is just a ratio..don't know if this helps.

Comment: I see what you did there, but it doesn't match the options given.
options are: A) (3/5:1/2) B) (23/82:-2/41) C) (23/41:-2/41) and D) (-23/82:2/41)

Comment: Well I interpreted the fraction the wrong way, let me edit.

Comment: What I did before was just totally wrong, I apologise. Now it's correct, and indeed the answer is B). Whenever dealing with fractions of complex numbers, multiply numerator and denominator with the complex conjugate of the denominator to get an expression of the form $a+bi$, and then go from there.